# Mail Merge using mutiple fields/next record

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word-2013, mail-merge

I am trying to merge the following:

```
{MERGEFIELD Signer}
Date
Page 2


{MERGEFIELD Payername} {MERGEFIELD Number} {MERGEFIELD Description} {MERGEFIELD Year}
PB
```

If the client has multiple Payer names, I need it to show:

```
{MERGEFIELD Signer}
Date
Page 2

{MERGEFIELD Payername} {MERGEFIELD Number} {MERGEFIELD Description} {MERGEFIELD Year}
{MERGEFIELD Payername} {MERGEFIELD Number} {MERGEFIELD Description} {MERGEFIELD Year}
PB
```

How do I insert the NEXT/IF rule?  I seem to be having trouble with this!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to merge more than one excel record into some documents. Word will only merge one record per document.

You might need to extend word's mail merge capabilities. I came across a similar problem a while back and now regularly use this:

http://www.gmayor.com/ManyToOne.htm

It's free and very useful (worth a donation if you like it)

If this doesn't fit the task perhaps you could adjust the excel data source in some way? Hard to say without seeing how your excel data is structured. Perhaps you could post a sample?

Another option would be to write your own VBA to extend word's mail merge capabilities but that's a whole world of hassle if you aren't a coder